# More advanced magnetic breadboard with software defined wires

Tags: breadboard

Since we could compile the netlist on a typical x86 like computer
and download it to a FPGA chip so everything is connected and functioning,

Why can't we extend the same idea to Mix Signal engineering with bread boards.

I mean SMD magnetic devices could easily mount on the breadboard surface using 
magnetism , and wires could be connected as the same way that connections were made
in FPGA chips?

My question is do you know such kind of device? What it named ?
If such device do exists.

And also why current breadboard technologies are not based on magnets?
What are the technological limitations why what I dreamed breadboard is not
in the radio-shack?

--Thanks in Advance --

Comment: may I ask why this is downvoted?

Comment: Speaking for myself: because you are just fantsasising, without much regard for your ideas being practical, and then you are ask the rethorical question "why isn't the world as it is in my dream?". I won't downvote, I'll vote to close.

Comment: it's alright completely. Actually but what I want is to know "Why it's impossible to have that technology?" , I know many companies out there already built that if it's possible.

Comment: EDIT: @WoutervanOoijen , I will improve question.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of my thoughts:

The mass market for components is to be soldered to a PCB and this is what components are optimized for. That you can use these components on a breadboard is an advantage for the user, but the manufacturer has little to non interest in that. Therefore you would need special breadboard-compatible components. You don't want to pay a $1 for a diode that costs  $0.005 just because it has magnetic/breadboard properties, let alone that you don't want to have a double stock (breadboard vs. production).

Breadboards already have huge parasitic capacitance, inductance and resistance from their own, you don't want huge amounts of extra wiring to increase these properties even further.

FPGA's are expensive, a regular breadboard sells for a few dollars/euro's.

Components on breadboards regularly release the magic blue smoke because of misconfigurations. You don't want the FPGA, probably being the most expensive part on the breadboard, to release its smoke.

It is much easier to quickly fiddle with wires than to upload netlists while experimenting.

Comment: what you mean by magic blue smoke?

Comment: A component only works while the magic blue smoke is contained inside the component. Once the magic blue smoke gets released in the open air, the component no longer works. It is important to keep that magic blue smoke inside the component.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke